# How to properly use s3 to deliver and store files in a web application?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, server

So we are planning to move static content to s3 for operational reasons. I just want to understand where to place s3 in the workflow of handling a request.

1. If website requires an image, should the request hit our service first which would fetch the image from s3 (reverse-proxy) or should client directly request the file.
2. How to hide file names ,pathnames and manage permissions in request for file?
3. Same questions applicable for uploading new content.
4. Handle s3 quota and parallel requests

Comment: 1. The request should hit cloudfront, which will then pass to S3. 2. The client must request fileanames, you can't hide them. 4. what quotas? S3/Cloudfront can handle an unlimited number of parallel requests.

Comment: To add to @jordanm's comment, if the content in S3 is private then you're going to need to authorize access to it. You can do that by proxying requests to the content (as you suggested) or your web server can create S3 pre-signed URLs for each file in S3 and inject those URLs into the web page content.

Comment: Pre-signed URLs are a great way to let your app manage access, but have S3 serve content. See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to comment, but this turned into a full answer instead...

1. Either. If your assets are public, the lowest-weight method is to just request them from a public S3 bucket. If they're not, though, it's probably easiest to use Cloudfront rather than rolling-your-own auth around S3 requests.
2. You can make it look like your asset `A.jpeg` in `S3.yourBucket/A.jpeg` is at `yourWebsite.com/A.jpeg` [using Cloudfront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html). If you want to *also* obscure the filename `A`, you need to use e.g. API gateway to serve you the file without revealing anything about it to your front end. If it were me, I wouldn't bother.
3. Unless you absolutely have to, don't let users upload to the same bucket that other users download from. There are several approaches to uploads depending on the use-case. [Pre-signed URL's](https://www.serverless.com/blog/s3-one-time-signed-url) are good for one-time use. You can also just provide the user with AWS credentials that are allowed to write-only to the upload bucket, by using [Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html).
4. There's no S3 quota. You get charged for reads and writes. For a simple site, these charges will be tiny. If you're worried, you can [use Cloudfront to rate-limit your users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/ddos-get-started-rate-based-rules.html). You can also use [API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-to-api.html) to create limits for individual users. S3 is extremely parallelizable.

Comment: Curiously asking, if I create a cloudfront and select the source from S3, will I get charged for S3 read based on the visitors?

Comment: @DominiqueAltrez Well yes, but Cloudfront does caching [and you can set how long you want objects to remain in the cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorS3Origin.html#RequestS3Caching) so in practice if you have many visitors and infrequently changing data in S3, your S3 requests (and S3 costs) would be much smaller than your Cloudfront requests (and Cloudfront costs) - note that [Cloudfront pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/) gives data origins in AWS (e.g. S3 or EC2) a partial discount